# Query MySQL from different Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I need to query database in AWS lambda functions using [MySQL npm module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). Should I open MySQL connection in each lambda function? Or I could reuse a single function?

Answer (score 1):

For each execution of Lambda, it needs to create a new connection and execute the mysql queries.

This is because Lambda run as [stateless](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html), in between different invocations.

If different Lambda functions need to query the database, each of them needs to connect to it.

Comment: That's true, but not the whole story. If you create the connection object outside the handler and set [`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) inside the handler, the same connection can be reused by non-concurrent invocations for as long as the container is alive.